# The dashboard returns 404 error page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am able to login to my Wordpress site but when i click on dashboard it shows 404 error page. I am not able edit the pages too.
[image]

Comment: Did you make any change on your WordPress like adding a plugin? Do you have access to your files via FTP?

Comment: @gael yup i added a plugin and then removed it. Don't have access to FTP.

Comment: What plugin? Did you solve your problem?*

Comment: Yeah the problem solved, the issue was fixed by the web developers.